# Probability problem regarding game of tossing coin

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> $A$ and $B$ play a game of tossing a fair coin. $A$ starts the game by tossing the coin once and $B$ then tosses the coin twice followed by $A$ tossing the coin once and $B$ tossing the coin twice. This continues until a head turns up. Whoever gets the first head wins the game. Which of the following is/are true.
>
> $(A)$ $P(B \ wins) > P(A \ wins)$
>
> $(B)$ $P(B \ wins) = 2P(A \ wins)$
>
> $(C)$ $P(B \ wins) < P(A \ wins)$
>
> $(D)$ $P(A \ wins) = 1-P(B \ wins)$

I feel that $A,B,D$, are correct by intuition but I am not sure how to approach this. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If there's a single correct answer then it is obviosly D.

Comment: @barakmanos No. There could be multiple correct options.

Comment: Just for intuition:  $A$ can win on the very first toss, and might possibly win on a later toss.  Thus it is clear that $P(A)>\frac 12$.

Answer (score 2):

$D$ is  obviously correct.

Calculate the probability that $A$ wins, this happens under the following situations: head comes first try, then head comes on the fourth toss and tails on the rest(A gets tails on his toss, and $B$ on his tosses), then head on the seventh toss and tails on the rest, head on the tenth toss and tails on the rest etc.

Hence, the probability that $A$ wins is :$ \frac 12 + \left( \frac 12 \right)^4 + \left( \frac 12 \right)^7 + \ldots$ Compute this value using the geometric series formula, and use $D$ to find the probability that $B$ wins. This will help you see which option is correct and which is not.

In our case, it is even clearer : $P(A) > \frac 12$, since $A$ will win on the first turn with probability half, and on further turns with positive probability. Therefore, in light of $D$, one may rule out $A$ and $B$, and see that $C$ is obviously true.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

These are the sequences that $A$ can win:

$H, TTTH, TTTTTTH, TTTTTTTTTH$

The probability is

$$\frac12+ \left(\frac12\right)^3 \frac12+\left(\frac12\right)^6 \frac12+\ldots> \frac12$$

Answer (score 1):

Without any work, it's instant that

- (D) is true: With probability 1, a head eventually appears, so A wins or B wins, but (of course) not both.
  (C) is true: Player A can win on the first toss, but can also possibly win after the first toss, so P(A) > 1/2.

  (A) is false (since (C) is true).

  (B) is false (since (A) is false).